# Set used values in an array to null

Tags: java, android, arrays, null

Hi I am trying to create a simple flag quiz app where an image of a flag appears and the user selects the correct answer from 3 options, however the app keeps crashing after two flags are shown. I think this might be something to do with a memory leak in the images array but I can't work out how to stop this. I am trying to set the images to null once they are shown but it shows an error when I try mapPics[i]=null; as shown below. The error says the image can not be set to null because it is an integer. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class game1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
   static Button next;
   static ImageView mainpic;
   static RadioGroup radioGroup;
   static RadioButton option1;
   static RadioButton option2;
   static RadioButton option3;
   static int[] mapPics = new int[]{R.drawable.america, R.drawable.england,     R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.poland, R.drawable.sweden, R.drawable.spain};
   static String [] answers= new String[]{"Spain", "Poland", "Sweden",  "America", "England", "Australia"};
   static int [] correctAnswer= new int[]{2, 1};
   static int score=0;
   static int i=0;
   static int a=0;
   static int b=1;
   static int c=2;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.game1);

      next= (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
      mainpic= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      mainpic.setImageResource(mapPics[i]);
      next.setOnClickListener(this);


      addListenerRadioGroup();
      option1.setText(String.valueOf(answers[a]));
      option2.setText(String.valueOf(answers[b]));
      option3.setText(String.valueOf(answers[c]));


   }//On Create

   public void addListenerRadioGroup(){
      option1= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
      option2= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
      option3= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
      radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAnswers);
      radioGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
     }
  });

  }


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
      getSelectedAnswer();
      i++;
      a=a+3;
      b=b+3;
      c=c+3;
      if(i >=1) {

     Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, scores.class);
     myIntent.putExtra("scores", score);
     startActivity(myIntent);

  }//if
  mainpic.setImageResource(mapPics[i]);
  option1.setText(String.valueOf(answers[a]));
  option2.setText(String.valueOf(answers[b]));
  option3.setText(String.valueOf(answers[c]));
  mapPics[i]=null;
  }//onClick

  public void getSelectedAnswer() {
  int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
  if (index==correctAnswer[i])
     score++;



   }//get selected answer

  }//class
```

Comment: Ya because mappings is integer n null is string type..n put manic.resources(mapPic [I]) inside a loop...

Comment: why'd this get a downvote?

Answer (score 4):

The error message you are getting is telling you exactly what the problem is.
You have declared `mapPics` as an array of `int`:

```
static int[] mapPics = new int[]{R.drawable.america, R.drawable.england,     R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.poland, R.drawable.sweden, R.drawable.spain};
```

`int` is a primitive type, so you cannot set it to null.  If you want a nullable type, use an `Integer[]` instead.